# How to use chroma.js with leaflet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am using [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and I am generating the polygons, then I am using [chroma.js](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#color-desaturate) like this:

```
function style(feature) {
    return {
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        fillColor: chroma.scale(['#fafa6e','#2A4858']).mode('lch').colors(6)
    };
}

var geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
    style: style,
}).addTo(map);
```

Why am I only getting one single fill color, dark, for all polygons instead of a range of colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `fillColor` to a list of colours. You need to pick out a specific colour based on the properties of `feature`.

This would work (based on one of the [official Leaflet demos](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/)).

```
var states = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {"color_id": 1},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-104.05, 48.99],
            [-97.22,  48.98],
            [-96.58,  45.94],
            [-104.03, 45.94],
            [-104.05, 48.99]
        ]]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {"color_id": 2},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-109.05, 41.00],
            [-102.06, 40.99],
            [-102.03, 36.99],
            [-109.04, 36.99],
            [-109.05, 41.00]
        ]]
    }
}];

colors = chroma.scale(['#fafa6e','#2A4858']).mode('lch').colors(6)

function style(feature) {
    return {
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        fillColor: colors[feature.properties.color_id]
    };
}

layer = L.geoJSON(states, {style: style}).addTo(map);
```